# Unable to Create a simulated device app on Azure IoT hub Java

Tags: java, azure

I am pretty new to Azure IoT Hub. I am using Java for its development and as a first step I am following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted/#) tutorial.
I was able to create a device identity and my receive messages from cloud module also executes fine. But when I try to execute device simulation module I get:

Error: Error{condition=amqp:connection:framing-error, description='org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: connection aborted', info=null}

Error: org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: connection aborted

I think it is something related to AMQPS configurations but not really sure what might be going wrong here.

Anyone ever faced such a problem ?

Comment: I reproduced the issue and collected more error information. I am trying to involve someone familiar with this topic to further look at this issue. There might be some time delay. Appreciate your patience.

Comment: Hey thanks Peter. If it gets solved then it will be worth the wait.

Answer (score 0):

@UmerF92,
Thanks for your patience. 
Could you please try this code below on your environment? The sample was followed the tutorial(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted/) and it worked fine on my side.

```
private static String connString = "HostName=<your hub>.azure-devices.net;"
            + "DeviceId=< your device >;"
            + "SharedAccessKey=<your share key >";
    private static IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.AMQPS;//or HTTPS
    private static boolean stopThread = false;


private static String DEVICEID="<your device id>";

private static class TelemetryDataPoint {
    public String deviceId;
    public double windSpeed;

    public String serialize() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
}

protected static class EventCallback implements IotHubEventCallback {
    public void execute(IotHubStatusCode statusCode, Object context) {
        System.out.println("IoT Hub responded to message with status " + statusCode.name());

        if (context != null) {
            synchronized (context) {
                context.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static class MessageSender implements Runnable {
    public volatile boolean stopThread = false;

    public void run() {
        try {
            double avgWindSpeed = 10;
            Random rand = new Random();
            DeviceClient client;

            client = new DeviceClient(connString, protocol);
            client.open();

            while (!stopThread) {
                double currentWindSpeed = avgWindSpeed + rand.nextDouble() * 4 - 2;
                TelemetryDataPoint telemetryDataPoint = new TelemetryDataPoint();

                telemetryDataPoint.deviceId = DEVICEID;
                telemetryDataPoint.windSpeed = currentWindSpeed;

                String msgStr = telemetryDataPoint.serialize();
                Message msg = new Message(msgStr);

                System.out.println(msgStr);

                Object lockobj = new Object();
                EventCallback callback = new EventCallback();

                client.sendEventAsync(msg, callback, lockobj);

                synchronized (lockobj) {
                    lockobj.wait();
                }

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            client.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
    MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
    Thread t0 = new Thread(messageSender);

    t0.start();

    System.out.println("Press ENTER to exit...");
    System.in.read();
    messageSender.stopThread = true;
    t0.join();
}
```

Please try it.

Any updates or concerns, please let me know.